# Theories/Models to explain the language evolution?

Tags: english, historical-linguistics, sociolinguistics

I'd like to read about the language evolution and the models related to it such as the Schneider's Model.

Any help? :)

Comment: If by "Schneider's Model" you mean Schmidt's Wave Theory, you could look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Schmidt_%28linguist%29

Comment: I suppose OP refers to Schneider's [Dynamic Model of Postcolonial Englishes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schneider's_dynamic_model). See for example his book on [Postcolonial English](http://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/sociolinguistics/postcolonial-english-varieties-around-world).